# Kill node.exe process in windows 2008 server

Tags: node.js

I have written a simple node api that listen on port 5005. I executed using command "node index.js", it runs perfectly. After some time, I wanted to close the node console by pressing "Ctrl + C" but it does not respond. I closed the command console directly; but it seems "node.exe" is there in the "task manager".

I tried to kill it but every time it says; access is denied. I am the administrator of the server. I need to do restart the server every time, I get this issue.

```
https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(5555, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port 5555!");
});
```

Comment: Tried using `taskkill`?

Comment: Have you opened the command prompt 'Run As administrator' ?

Comment: @Milan: Yes, I already tried using taskkill also WMIC kill process

Comment: @Edwin: No I just opened the command prompt normally.

Comment: Well give it a try to opened it with "run as administrator." See if the access denied will come back....

Comment: @Edwin No help. It again stuck. I can't kill node.exe from processes.